# Cloudfront CDN for s3 data that is accessed in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

I have an AWS API Gateway connected to Lambda that serves some tiny data which is residing in a S3 bucket. The API Gateway and Lambda is in US East 1. I was wondering if I distribute the content in S3 (that is getting loaded in Lambda) using Cloudfront will it improve network latency of the endpoint?

Currently, it is about 500ms in US, 800ms in Europe and 1100ms in Asia.

Answer (score 0):

The basic answer is yes it will improve latency from the end users perspective.

For a comprehensive breakdown see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49534818/7529276

Answer (score 0):

Yes! it will reduce the latency since fewer intermediates nodes involved and you have control over caching.

S3 -> Lambda -> API Gateway (+ Internal CloudFront Distribution) **vs** S3 -> CloudFront

Also, make sure you configure the correct TTL values with CloudFront so that the serverside caching take effect.